# How to Reference a pgfplotstable

Tags: cross-referencing, pgfplotstable, labels

I am still generating a table from a `cvs` file with the `pgfplotstable` package. In my text I will reference to the generated table but I did not know how to do this. Normal your make a `\label{tab:foo}` and in the text you can reference to `\ref{tab:foo}`. How can I do this with the pgfplotstable? For more you can see my code

```
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
    \begin{document}

    Here should be a text which is referencing to the Table~\ref{tab:foo}. But I did not know how to make a label at the table.

        \pgfplotstableset{
        begin table=\begin{longtable},
        end table=\end{longtable},
        }

        \pgfplotstabletypeset[
            col sep=semicolon,
            string type,
            columns/Hersteller/.style={column name=Hersteller, column type={l}},
            columns/Produktname/.style={column name=Produktname, column type={l}},
            columns/Betriebssystem/.style={column name=Betriebssystem, column type={l}},
            columns/Version/.style={column name=Version, column type={l}},
            every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\toprule},
            every last row/.style={after row=\hline caption={foo}},
            ]{./files/NFCDeviceTabletStand20121230.csv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it just as with standard LaTeX `tabular` environments: using the `table` environment. The referencing mechanism is independent of `pgfplotstable` (which is nothing more but a generator of `tabular` environments).

It looks like this:

```
\begin{table}
\pgfplotstabletypeset ...

\caption{The caption}
\label{tab:foo}
\end{table}
```